# location.hash in the select tag

Tags: javascript, select, hash, onchange

I have created a page with a list of addresses categorized by italian provinces.
At the Top of page I have a **`<select>`** tag with list of all the provinces `<option>`, I have assigned to this `<select>` the **onChange** event to generate different URLs for each province.

```
<form class="form" action="java-script:update();">  
        <select name="cities" id="cities" onchange = "update(); location.hash = '?id=' + this.value">  
                 <option value = "Bologna">Bologna</option>  
                 <option value = "Milano">Milano</option>  
                 <option value = "Roma">Roma</option> 
        </select> 
</form>
```

### **My problem is:**

For example, if I copy the link of another province (eg http://mywebsite.it/page.html#?id=Roma) and open a new tab and paste it in the address bar, and I submit, always reminds me to position on the first *option* (in this case, Bologna).
Why?

Thanks! and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the selected option at all, you just change the hash when the user changes the selected option. Nothing fancy happens, because you do not reuse the hash.

If you want to select the current option on page load for example, you'd need to execute some JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var city = location.hash.substring(5); // strip the #?id=
    var elem = document.getElementById('cities');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
        if(elem.options[i].value == city) {
            elem.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Also, to use JavaScript in an URL, use `javascript:`, not `java-script:`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ez8dY/1/ (select a city, then reload the frame)

Comment: Also, don't use javascript in URLs. Add an event handler for the form's `submit` event.

Comment: @Phoenix: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. The select option does not change indeed, because you do not have any code that sets the selected option do you? And my code does not work on your page because you have some numbers behind the city or something.